# Google Places API billing each request individually despite using AutocompleteSessionToken

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am working on an Android application that utilizes the Google Places API to fetch autocomplete suggestions, and later fetch details about a place selected by the user. According to the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete), using an `AutocompleteSessionToken` should allow grouping the autocomplete and place details requests into a single billable session. However, even when using an `AutocompleteSessionToken`, each request is being billed individually.

Here's how I am using the `AutocompleteSessionToken` in my code:

```
java
// In the getAutocompletePredictions method
if (useSessionToken) {
    sessionToken = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();
    requestBuilder.setSessionToken(sessionToken);
}

// In the lookUpPlaceByID method
if (sessionToken != null) {
    request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeID, selectedFields)
        .setSessionToken(sessionToken)
        .build();
}
```

I have verified through log tags, and the same AutocompleteSessionToken is being used for both requests. However, in the Google Cloud console, I see that the number of requests billed by the Places API is 2.

```
Log.d(TAG, "Session Token: " + sessionToken.toString());
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before and has a solution? Is there something I might be missing in utilizing the AutocompleteSessionToken to group the requests?

Comment: Autocomplete have 3 diferrent billing SKUs, [Autocomplete – Per Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#ac-per-request), [Autocomplete without Place Details – Per Session](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#ac-no-details-session), and [Autocomplete (included with Place Details) – Per Session](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#ac-with-details-session). Can you please clarify which are the ones you can see in your billing?

Comment: Hi @Yrll , I use the Autocomplete option with session but without details. When a user selects a place, I call Place Details using the same session token from Autocomplete. At the end of the Place Details method, I use the following line of code to reset the token:
sessionToken = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();

Comment: To avoid assumptions on our end, and since I can't take a look at your project or what you are being billed at, I'd highly suggest that you [file a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support) so that Tech agents can take a look at your project internally and help you better.